# Magento 2.2.8 Redirects to Blank Pages from Contact Form and Backend Help

Tags: magento2, php-7, server-setup

Yesterday I updated to Magento 2.2.8. Now, I'm having serious issues that I'm not even sure what triggers them.

Firstly, yesterday, I was having issues with the SMTP (Mageplaza SMTP module) - when I try to send test mail, the error

```
"A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."
```

keeps showing. In trying to resolve the outgoing emails issues I went ahead and enabled "Asynchronous sending" from Sales > Sales Emails.

This did not resolve anything. So I went back to disable it only to find out that I'm unable to. When I choose "disable" and click "Save Config" I get a blank page. When I use the browser back button the setting has not changed.

The same blank page issue I have on the Contact form. When I submit the contact form I get redirected to a blank page at

```
https://example.com/contact/index/post/
```

And I receive no messages from the contact form.

Please, help me with these issues. I have no idea what causes them. Is the 2.2.8 version broken? Do I need to fix something else? Any suggestions are welcome. :(

Comment: Can you find anything in magento  and server logs?

Comment: in cron.log I see the following errors:

    main.ERROR: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails has an error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::getHeaders(). Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":96468992,"emalloc_start":83132576} [] []

Comment: Also: [2019-04-03 09:33:22] main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when running a cron job at /home/formbath/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:324, Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Magento\\Framework\\Mail\\Message\\Interceptor::getHeaders() at /home/formbath/public_html/vendor/mageplaza/module-smtp/Mail/Rse/Mail.php:203)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with Mageplaza SMTP module. The Module latest version seems to be working fine with Magento 2.2.8 or 2.3.1. So kindly enable the developer mode in Module Configuration, enable debug in configuration to check where the issue occurs. I didn't find any error with this line

> Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::getHeaders() at
>   /home/formbath/public_html/vendor/**mageplaza/module-smtp/Mail/Rse/Mail.php**:203)

since it seems to be working fine with the same version Magento 2.2.8 please let me know the version you are using also please try to compile and deploy commands with appropriate permissions to debug further

Comment: Yes, I figured that and did all required updates and re-deployments. Thank you! However, now I'm having another issue related to server SSL certificate verification failure when trying to send mail via the SMTP

Comment: please check this link can be useful for you https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/1

Comment: Thanks for your help! :-) I confirm that the SMTP issues are all resolved now. Magento cron immediately ran and sent out the queued messages. However, now I will need to work out the CA certificate issue, as I want to use server.example.com, instead of mail.example.com - currently, the first one throws the certificate failure error. While the second option works, but all messages land in the Spam inbox. The link you're giving me contains the exact issue that I have indeed. I will now look into this.